# How to temporarily disable docker support from asp.net core 2.0 project in visual studio 2017 ver 15.3.2?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I created Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web Api project in Visual Studio 2017 ver 15.3.2 with Docker support enabled.

How can I temporarily disable Docker support from project?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Solution explorer right-click on docker project ("docker compose") and select "Unload project"

Answer (score 2):

Although I have not installed Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3.2, I dealt with the same issue in **Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9** by following the steps below to *disable docker support* from my **ASP .NET Core 2.1** :

1. Solution Explore -> Right click on 'docker-compose' -> Unload project
2. Solution Explore -> Right click on ASP .NET Core project -> Set as StarUp Project
3. Solution Explore -> Right click on ASP .NET Core project -> Properties -> Debug tab -> Profile and Launch menu -> IIS Express

Now you have to Rebuild Solution and then Run your project in 'IIS Express' mode.

Answer (score 1):

I removed following from sln file to remove docker support:

```
Project("{E53339B2-1760-4266-BCC7-CA923CBCF16C}") = "docker-compose", "docker-compose.dcproj", "{5412559A-5688-4EB3-97F4-31DF8997843C}"
EndProject
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this snippet you provided this is not located in **csproj** but in the main **sln** file. Also, if I remember well, to fully revert what "add docker support" does, he should delete any `dockerfile`s that were added to projects in the solution.. but of course that's not always wanted.

Comment: I have changed it to sln in answer. Also I wanted to remove temporarily only so that I could enable it later by adding the same back to sln file. I have updated question as well to reflect that. Thanks @quetzalcoatl for pointing it out.